# Swapping two columns without updating

Tags: sql, swap

I'm working on a football league, and I need to insert the second leg matches, how can I swap the home team with the away team without an update?

I already have every game for leg 1 with the columns:

game_id Home Away

and the data:

```
1 Team A x Team B
2 Team C x Team D
3 Team E x Team F
```

I want to insert this on the table:

```
4 Team B x Team A
5 Team D x Team C
6 Team F x Team E
```

in order for it to stay:

```
1 Team A x Team B
2 Team C x Team D
3 Team E x Team F
4 Team B x Team A
5 Team D x Team C
6 Team F x Team E
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I was only trying to insert manually, but i already got the answer. Thanks

Comment: don't add 'SOLVED' on the question title, you can accept the answer from Tree Frog. First of all, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help), you'll know how to accept, upvote / downvote an answer / question.
Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Id is an auto generated identity field you should just be able to do

```
insert into league (teamA, teamB) select teamB, teamA from league
```